# Print a rollback query of a update query using a query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to print the rollback query of a update query.
My original query is

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET NAME = 'SAMAN' WHERE ID=4;
```

The corresponding update for above query is

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET NAME=(SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID=4);
```

I need to print a query to rollback if above original query went wrong. I need it to print it via using a query also.
I'm using oracle 11g database.

Comment: You can't "print" a rollback.   Please detail better.  You two update statements are identical, no?  Why do you want to update **every** rows in EMPLOYEE table with name from ID=4?

Comment: Sorry.I have edited the query again. I need to be print the query in a row or in a column.

Comment: THis still makes no sense.  Sorry.

Comment: It might help to explain what you need this for.  You could possibly do this with [Oracle LogMiner](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm#i1016535), but this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by running a select query like below,

```
SELECT 'UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET NAME = '''||name||''' WHERE id = '||id||';' FROM employee;
```

and of course, run the select query before your update query.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, it is some kind of a *log* table you're looking for. I have no idea what you mean by "printing the rollback query"; never heard of anything like that.

So, let me demonstrate what I have on my mind. Review it, apply if it makes sense in your case. The code is commented, I hope you'll understand it

Prepare the scene:

```
SQL> -- Log table
SQL> create table emp_log
  2    (id    number   constraint pk_el primary key,
  3     empno number   constraint fk_el_emp references emp (empno) not null,
  4     datum date     not null,
  5     ename varchar2(20)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> -- A sequence which will be used to populate the ID column in the EMP_LOG table
SQL> create sequence seqa;

Sequence created.

SQL> -- Trigger; if new ENAME is different from the last one, log the change (i.e.
SQL> -- store the old ENAME)
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_emp
  2    before update on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.ename <> :old.ename then
  6       insert into emp_log (id, empno, datum, ename)
  7       values (seqa.nextval, :new.empno, sysdate, :old.ename);
  8    end if;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

OK, let's see how it works:

```
SQL> -- Some employees in department 10
SQL> select empno, ename from emp where deptno = 10;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK
      7839 KING
      7934 MILLER

SQL> -- Update KING's name to a better one (just kidding)
SQL> update emp set ename = 'LITTLEFOOT' where empno = 7839;

1 row updated.

SQL> -- What's in the log?
SQL> select * From emp_log order by id desc;

        ID      EMPNO DATUM               ENAME
---------- ---------- ------------------- --------------------
         5       7839 30.03.2018 20:22:15 KING

SQL> -- I don't like the new name after all; return the previous one
SQL> update emp e set
  2    e.ename = (select l.ename from emp_log l
  3               where l.empno = e.empno
  4                 and l.id = (select max(l1.id) from emp_log l1
  5                             where l1.empno = l.empno
  6                            )
  7              )
  8  where e.empno = 7839;

1 row updated.

SQL> -- What we've done?
SQL> select empno, ename from emp where deptno = 10;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK
      7839 KING
      7934 MILLER

SQL> -- What's in the log now?
SQL> select * From emp_log order by id desc;

        ID      EMPNO DATUM               ENAME
---------- ---------- ------------------- --------------------
         6       7839 30.03.2018 20:22:33 LITTLEFOOT
         5       7839 30.03.2018 20:22:15 KING

SQL>
```